# how to set owner and permission to a cryptsetup made device?

Tags: permissions, filesystem, encryption, system, udev

I have an encrypted loopback volume. I need to `mount` and `umount` the volume manually, so I use `cryptsetup luksOpen` and `cryptsetup luksClose` .

However, under all sessions (gnome/xfce/kde/unity), when I invoke this command it pops up the /dev/mapper device  ...

And then it lets the one user mount (with password), access files, and unmount the volume.

It's quite annoying in a multi user server (you are working on your files and the volume is being unmounted). I want the volume to be owned and used by only root and the owner and not all users.

**How can I define ownership and permission on the device ?**

More informations :

- I've tried `chown` and `chmod` approach witch gives nothing.
- Cryptsetup doesn't have any options that let you do that.
- crypttab auto mount the filesystem on boot witch is unwanted (only manual mount)

The permissions that cryptsetup put in the `/dev/mapper/MyEncryptedVolume` is owner `root:root` but with `lrwxrwxrwx`

whatever I do (like a chmod) won't do anything.

It's a device (`/dev/mapper/MyEncryptedVolume`) that is linked to `/dev/dm-0` with rights `brw-rw----`

I've changed the rights of `/dev/dm-0` with `udev` rule but nothing change : the volume is still shown to normal users due to the symbolic link.

Thank you

Comment: Ok My trouble wasn't with Cryptsetup but with losetup. However the udev rules had an impact for owner and permission. Going to post the answer to this question soon.

Comment: Please [edit] this question to replace `witch` with `which` so that online language translators can work properly.  While editing, the `Thank you` should be removed as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reality is that Cryptsetup uses Loop devices / Losetup in order to mount a loopback file to `/dev/mapper/MyEncryptedVolume`.

`udev` can resolve the situation.

There is two options : let cryptsetup choose the loopdevice or dedicate a loop device for this.

I chose the second part.

In this example I use `/dev/loop5`

1. Create a file named `99-myspecial.rules` into the folder `/etc/udev/rules.d/`
2. insert this :

   `KERNEL=="loop5" MODE="0600" OWNER="MyUser" GROUP="MyGroupUser" ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}="1" ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE}="1" ENV{ID_DRIVE_EJECTABLE}="0"`

   This tells `udisk` (witch is the real trouble maker in that situation) to ignore the volume, to hide the icon, that the volume is not ejectable (aka it's not a cdrom). You also specify that only one user can access to that volume.
3. Then Restart udev service
4. Then I link the loop device like this :

   ```
   losetup /folder/myflatfile.img /dev/loop5
   ```

And then I use cryptsetup as I want with the loop device as source.

Hopes that helps someone more than me.